# Foursquare OAuth2.0 request does not work after Apache & PHP upgrade

Tags: apache, foursquare

I have foursquare app that gets authorization from Foursquare. It used to work but after the server upgrade it stopped working as timeout after 30 seconds.

We were using Apache 2.2.6 and PHP 5.2.12 and upgraded it to Apache 2.2.22 & PHP 5.3.17. We updated php codes according to 5.3.17 which are mostly db stuff. Anyhow our Foursquare server side app isn’t not working since. We tried it on other old server with old setup, then it works.

Specifically, access token is not returned on the request for authorization on our app when a user try to use it.

We are using this format below for making the request.

`https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token
    ?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
    &client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET
    &grant_type=authorization_code
    &redirect_uri=YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI
    &code=CODE`

All of values are filled accordingly.

Any hint or clue would be helpful!

Comment: Any returning error, like « redirect_uri_mismatch »? About time out error, you sure curl (or whatever you are using to call the access token) does work with any other url?

Comment: I get timeout with 500 Network error. I had redirect_uri_mismatch before but that was taken care of from foursquare api setting and our configuration in the code. 
We have several servers and only upgraded servers don't work with same code. (Of course I changed settings from Foursquare api setting and our url stuff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try requesting the URL from your browser, and seeing the response generated. This should give you more information about the error occurring.

In your browser, you can imitate a user and follow the flow that they would use to authorize your app. Then, you can take the code parameter from the url, and visit the access_token link in your browser to see the response.

Comment: Thanks! I did that using request url on a browser. Found out it was curl issue somehow. Played with curl for sometime simplifying a bit, and working good now.